# Is there a law in Japan that dogs in public spaces must be leashed at all times?

Tags: legal, japan, pets

All dogs I've ever seen here were on leash but this of course doesn't mean that there is a law. My Japanese is not good enough to read law texts about this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: I’m voting to reopen this question as it would be very relevant to travellers travelling with their pets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a distilled version of the laws available for [US Military personnel](http://www.housing.af.mil/shared/media/document/AFD-111108-079.pdf) or some [expatriates forum](http://japan.angloinfo.com/family/pets/):

> **Owning Pets Animals in Japan**
>
> *Information on the rules and regulations
> related to owning and caring for cats, dogs and other pet animals in
> Japan...*
>
> Most municipalities in Japan require a new pet dog to be registered
> within 30 days from the date of ownership. Registration is carried out
> at the local municipal office or ward office in the municipality in
> which the owner resides. In most cases, proof of identity of the owner
> is required; check with the local office for any additional document
> requirements. Once registration is complete a dog licence tag is
> provided, which should be attached to the dog's collar.
>
> Any change in address, ownership or in the event of the dog's death
> must be reported to the ward office. In addition, the municipality can
> assist with proper disposal of deceased dogs.
>
> **Buying Pets**
>
> Not all apartment buildings accept pets. Before purchasing a pet, check the lease agreement, or consult the landlord.
>
> **Vaccinations**
>
> Dogs must be vaccinated against rabies each year between
> 1 April and 30 June. Also, newly acquired dogs must be vaccinated
> within 30 days of ownership if it is over 90 days old. The rabies
> vaccination tag should be attached to the dog's collar.
>
> Other vaccinations are not required by law; however, they are
> recommended for the continued health of the dog. One exception is for
> imported dogs, which must be up to date with vaccinations.
>
> For further information, see the section on Importing Pets & Animals
> to Japan
>
> **Dogs in Public Places**
>
> Dogs must be kept on a leash when out for a
> walk. Dogs are generally not allowed in restaurants and shops. Small
> pets are allowed on public transport in a carrier. Guide dogs are
> permitted on public transport.
>
> The owner is responsible for cleaning up after their dog.
>
> There are no restricted dog breeds in Japan.
>
> **Information for Cat Owners**
>
> The Tokyo Metropolitan Government recommends that cat owners:
>
> Keep their cat inside the home Sterilise/neuter/spay the cat. Some
> municipal offices help pay part of the fee for neutering the cat Use a
> collar marked with the address and name of the owner In addition, the
> local municipal office can assist in the proper disposal of deceased
> cats.
>
> Vaccinations for cats are not required by law; however, they are
> recommended for the cat's long-term health.
>
> **Other Pet Animals**
>
> Dogs and cats are the most popular pets in Tokyo.
> However, due to many landlords restricting dog and cat ownership,
> smaller pets are also popular including fish, turtles, hamsters and
> ferrets. Certain animals are categorised as special animals and
> require permission to own in Japan. These restricted special animals
> are generally those that can attack people such as monkeys, eagles,
> hawks, crocodiles and snakes. Permission to own these animals is
> required from the local municipality office.